# Is there a command to list all users? Also to add, delete, modify users, in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, user-management

I need a command to list all users as well as commands to add, delete and modify users from terminal - any commands that could help in administrating user accounts easily by terminal.

Comment: sed answer `sed 's/:.*//' /etc/passwd`

Comment: list users: `awk -F: '{ print $1 }' /etc/passwd `

Comment: On ubuntu default using bash: ```grep bash /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1```

Answer (score 1395, accepted):

#### To list

To list all ***local*** users you can use:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
```

To list all users capable of authenticating (in some way), including non-local, see [this reply](https://askubuntu.com/a/414561/571941).

Some more useful user-management commands (also limited to ***local*** users):

#### To add

To add a new user you can use:

```
sudo adduser new_username
```

or:

```
sudo useradd new_username
```

See also: [What is the difference between adduser and useradd?](https://askubuntu.com/q/345974/147044)

#### To remove/delete

To remove/delete a user, first you can use:

```
sudo userdel username
```

Then you may want to delete the home directory for the deleted user account :

```
sudo rm -r /home/username
```

<sup>Please use with caution the above command!</sup>

#### To modify

To modify the username of a user:

```
usermod -l new_username old_username
```

To change the password for a user:

```
sudo passwd username
```

To change the shell for a user:

```
sudo chsh username
```

To change the details for a user (for example real name):

```
sudo chfn username
```

To add a user to the `sudo` group:

```
adduser username sudo
```

or

```
usermod -aG sudo username
```

And, of course, see also: `man adduser`, `man useradd`, `man userdel`... and so on.

Comment: Radu forgot to mention ```sudo chfn <username>``` which changes user details (for example real name). I tried to add this as a comment, but I got error telling me that I must have +50 reputation to do so.

Comment: I think that it should be underlined that the correct answer to the linked question is http://askubuntu.com/a/381646/16395 --- otherwise you have to take into account the GID/UID Ubuntu policies by hand. The accepted answer is not so clear.

Comment: sudo userdel DOMAIN\\johndoe gives me the error: "userdel: cannot remove entry 'DOMAIN\johndoe' from /etc/passwd -- I looked in /etc/passwd and they're not even in there, likely because it's a "domain" account?

Comment: @00fruX Yeah... If you're using a centralised user database you're going to need to deal with it directly.

Comment: What if cat returns access denied /etc/passwd, although this happens on root account ?

Comment: +1 for [What is the difference between adduser and useradd?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/345974/what-is-the-difference-between-adduser-and-useradd)

Comment: You could make this longer and exclude user nobody, but here's adding to the *list* command above for getting local users you created (>= 1000): `cut -d: -f1,3 /etc/passwd | grep -P '\d{4,}$'`

Comment: Becuase of this answer I learned about `cut` (using `man cut`)

Comment: To delete a user including its home directory, you can use `sudo deluser --remove-home <USERNAME>`. `sudo rm -r /home/username` is not only dangerous, because you can easily delete the wrong directory by a typo, but also because it does not necessarily have to be named after the user you want to delete (see `/etc/passwd`).

Answer (score 115):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

OR

```
less /etc/passwd
more /etc/passwd
```

You can also  use awk:<sup>[awk](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Awk.html)</sup>

```
awk -F':' '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: how to add users by command ?

Comment: You can use [useradd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd) command.

Comment: @nux A bit late to the party, but from command line use `adduser` instead, `useradd` should be limited to scripts where the author really really knows what he is doing.

Answer (score 80):

The easiest way to get this kind of information is `getent` - see [manpage for the `getent` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/getent). While that command gives the same output as `cat /etc/passwd` it is useful to remember because it will give you lists of several elements in the OS.

To get a list of all users you type (as users are listed in `/etc/passwd`)

```
getent passwd
```

To add a user *newuser* to the system you would type

```
sudo adduser newuser
```

to create a user that has all default settings applied.

Bonus: To add any user (for instance *anyuser*) to a group (for instance *cdrom*) type

```
sudo adduser anyuser cdrom
```

You delete a user (for instance *obsolete*) with

```
sudo deluser obsolete
```

If you want to delete his home directory/mails as well you type

```
sudo deluser --remove-home obsolete
```

And

```
sudo deluser --remove-all-files obsolete
```

will remove the user **and** all files owned by this user on the whole system.

Comment: It's useful to remember that getent doesn't just print the output of users in /etc/passwd but all users in all configured userdb backends on a given system, whether it's /etc/passwd or LDAP, etc.

Comment: @MarcinKaminski is right, it also prints users setup in SSO systems who have access to the server. this answer is the the best one, with `getent passwd` being the right command

Comment: @MarcinKaminski from all *enumerable* userdb backends

Comment: Yes you can find the user through getent and /etc/passwd. I found an article on this-
https://dev2devs.com/how-to-list-all-user-accounts-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04/

Answer (score 56):

You can use `compgen` [GNU bash built-in](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) too:

```
compgen -u
```

Will lists all users.

Answer (score 35):

This should get, *under most normal situations*, all normal (non-system, not weird, etc) users:

```
awk -F'[/:]' '{if ($3 >= 1000 && $3 != 65534) print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

This works by:

- reading in from `/etc/passwd`
- using `:` as a delimiter
- if the third field (the User ID number) is larger than 1000 and not 65534, the first field (the username of the user) is printed.

This is because on many linux systems, usernames above 1000 are reserved for  unprivileged (you could say normal) users. Some info on this [here](http://www.linfo.org/uid.html):

> A user ID (UID) is a unique positive integer assigned by a Unix-like
>   operating system to each user. Each user is identified to the system
>   by its UID, and user names are generally used only as an interface for
>   humans.
>
> UIDs are stored, along with their corresponding user names and other
>   user-specific information, in the /etc/passwd file...
>
> The third field contains the UID, and the fourth field contains the
>   group ID (GID), which by default is equal to the UID for all ordinary
>   users.
>
> In the Linux kernels 2.4 and above, UIDs are unsigned 32-bit integers
>   that can represent values from zero to 4,294,967,296. However, it is
>   advisable to use values only up to 65,534 in order to maintain
>   compatibility with systems using older kernels or filesystems that can
>   only accommodate 16-bit UIDs.
>
> The UID of 0 has a special role: it is always the root account (i.e.,
>   the omnipotent administrative user). Although the user name can be
>   changed on this account and additional accounts can be created with
>   the same UID, neither action is wise from a security point of view.
>
> The UID 65534 is commonly reserved for nobody, a user with no system
>   privileges, as opposed to an ordinary (i.e., non-privileged) user.
>   This UID is often used for individuals accessing the system remotely
>   via FTP (file transfer protocol) or HTTP (hypertext transfer
>   protocol).
>
> UIDs 1 through 99 are traditionally reserved for special system users
>   (sometimes called pseudo-users), such as wheel, daemon, lp, operator,
>   news, mail, etc. These users are administrators who do not need total
>   root powers, but who perform some administrative tasks and thus need
>   more privileges than those given to ordinary users.
>
> Some Linux distributions (i.e., versions) begin UIDs for
>   non-privileged users at 100. Others, such as Red Hat, begin them at
>   500, and still others, such Debian, start them at 1000. Because of the
>   differences among distributions, manual intervention can be necessary
>   if multiple distributions are used in a network in an organization.
>
> Also, it can be convenient to reserve a block of UIDs for local users,
>   such as 1000 through 9999, and another block for remote users (i.e.,
>   users elsewhere on the network), such as 10000 to 65534. The important
>   thing is to decide on a scheme and adhere to it.
>
> Among the advantages of this practice of reserving blocks of numbers
>   for particular types of users is that it makes it more convenient to
>   search through system logs for suspicious user activity.
>
> Contrary to popular belief, it is not necessary that each entry in the
>   UID field be unique. However, non-unique UIDs can cause security
>   problems, and thus UIDs should be kept unique across the entire
>   organization. Likewise, recycling of UIDs from former users should be
>   avoided for as long as possible.

Comment: Almost a perfect answer, but IMO it's cleaner to use `getent` instead of reading straight from `/etc/passwd` and lookup `UID_MIN`/`UID_MAX` instead of hard-coding the values: `getent passwd | awk -F: "{if (\$3 >= $(awk '/^UID_MIN/ {print $2}' /etc/login.defs) && \$3 <= $(awk '/^UID_MAX/ {print $2}' /etc/login.defs)) print \$1}"`

Answer (score 19):

**list** of all users who can login (no system users like: bin,deamon,mail,sys, etc.)

```
awk -F':' '$2 ~ "\$" {print $1}' /etc/shadow
```

**add** new user

```
sudo adduser new_username
```

or

```
sudo useradd new_username
```

**delete**/remove username

```
sudo userdel username
```

If you want to delete the home directory (default the directory /home/username)

```
sudo deluser --remove-home username
```

or

```
sudo rm -r /path/to/user_home_dir
```

If you want to delete all files from the system from this user (not only is the home diretory)

```
sudo deluser --remove-all-files
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain the difference between `adduser` and `useradd`. An also add the `sudo`-prefix to the first command. The password shadow file can only be read as root.

Comment: `awk -F':' '$2 ~ "\$" {print $1}' /etc/shadow` showed me all user including bin, daemon, etc. and threw this warning: escape sequence `\$' treated as plain `$'  I found this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/25867768/847954  and added one more backslash and it worked fine: `awk -F':' '$2 ~ "\\$" {print $1}' /etc/shadow`

Answer (score 8):

Ok here is a trick that will help you sort this. The terminal has auto completion if you type user and hit Tab key twice it will list all the commands that exist with user as the first 4 chars.

```
user (tab tab)
```

gives me as possible options
    useradd      userdel      usermod      users        users-admin
if you want to know more about a command google it or type man 
    man useradd
gives
    useradd - create a new user or update default new user information 
    ...
    ...

to list users you should go with what Mitch said.

Hope that helps I love tab completion in bash saves me from remembering things.

Comment: And this method is probably using compgen behind the scenes, see this other answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/925312/830543

Answer (score 8):

To find out the users which have home-directories in the /home-folder on the machine, run the following commands

```
cd /home
ls
```

You can then see the users who have authorization to log into the server. If we want to look into the files of any users, you must be the root user.

Comment: This only shows the content of `/home`. While Ubuntu puts user directories there by default, it's in no way mandatory.

Comment: `ls /home` may also contain user directories of deleted users.

Answer (score 2):

The first answer recommends:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
```

But using this and counting number of users you get:

```
$ cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | wc -l
46
```

46 users for a laptop computer are a lot!. So use this instead:

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep -vE '(/bin/false|/sbin/nologin|/bin/sync)' | cut -d: -f1
root
rick
guest-atkb2q
guest-u4sf2i
guest-rmlbtg
guest-mz53vp
```

To remove guest accounts (who don't have saved files anyway) use:

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep -vE '(/bin/false|/sbin/nologin|/bin/sync|guest-)' | cut -d: -f1
root
rick
```

Some sample users removed from the listing are:

```
systemd-timesync:x:100:102:systemd Time Synchronization,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
guest-atkb2q:x:999:999:Guest:/tmp/guest-atkb2q:/bin/bash
```

It turns out most of the users on a single user system are actually programs that have set themselves up as users.

Answer (score 2):

### [`lslogins`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lslogins.1.html)

> lslogins (1) - display information about known users in the system

`lslogins` is a Linux command that displays information about known users on a system. It gathers information from various sources such as `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group`, and other system-specific user information databases. The command scans the `wtmp` and `btmp` logs, the `/etc/shadow` (if necessary) and `/etc/passwd` files, and outputs the desired data. The optional username parameter can be used to output information only for the specified user.