# Remove a domain user account from local workstation, not from AD Domain

Tags: user-management, active-directory

I have an AD Domain run by Samba4 and have successfully joined Ubuntu workstations to that domain and able to add users and log into the workstation with domain accounts.  Now, I am needing to remove a domain account from that workstation so that only the end user who will be using that workstation has an account on that system--so that the temporary domain account used to configuration does not show up in the GDM login screen..  I know how to remove local users but I cannot find how to remove a domain account from said workstation.  Looking online and google only tells me how to remove a domain account completely from the domain.  I think it may be in my terminology when I run my search but I am not sure.

Thank you in advance.

Scott

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the domain useres home directory under `/home`. Ubuntu doesn't store any domain user files outside `/home`

Comment: OK.  I will do that.  Had no idea it was that easy!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Simply removing the home folder did **not** work for me.

```
rm -r /home/user_to_remove
```

Another suggested solution was to use the following command:

```
sudo userdel --remove-home user_to_remove
```

But the command said could not find user. In case it was a misspelled I tried to list all available users with:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
```

From this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/410274

The user was not in the list. The answer above specifically highlighted that it only listed **local** users.

**TL;DR;**

What finally worked was to go into:

Settings -> Users

Then click on the "user_to_remove" and then "Remove User..." button.