# How could I list all super users?

Tags: command-line, sudo

I want a command to list all users who have root privileges i.e. sudo  ?

Suppose I'm a sudoer user. How could I know all other sudoer users?

Comment: Here is the answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140974/107084

Comment: I find this one nice http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50785/how-do-i-find-out-if-i-am-sudoer

Comment: @JoKeR nice and tricky

Comment: Note that only [Joker](http://askubuntu.com/a/611601/216503) and [muru](http://askubuntu.com/a/611646/216503)'s answers are correct, only parsing user/group conf files does not give you who has the `sudo` permission and who has not....if a user is in `sudo` group but the `sudoers` file has nothing mentioned for `sudo` group, then?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

If you just need to list the sudoers listed in the `sudo` group, I think that the best way to do it would be to run this command (which *should* be computationally lighter than any of the other commands in this answer):

```
grep -Po '^sudo.+:\K.*$' /etc/group
```

Also as suggested in the comments by muru, the format of the entries in `/etc/group` can be easily handled by `cut`:

```
grep '^sudo:.*$' /etc/group | cut -d: -f4
```

Also again as suggested in the comments by muru, one can use `getent` in place of `grep`:

```
getent group sudo | cut -d: -f4
```

Any of these commands will print all the users listed in the `sudo` group in `/etc/group` (if any).

Command #1 breakdown:

- `grep`: Prints all the lines matching a regex in a file
- `-P`: makes `grep` match Perl-style regexes
- `o`: makes `grep` print only the matched string
- `'^sudo.+:\K.*$'`: makes `grep` match the regex between the quotes

Regex #1 breakdown:

- Any character or group of characters not listed matches the character or the group of characters itself
- `^`: start of line
- `.+`: one or more characters
- `\K`: discard the previous match
- `.*`: zero or more characters
- `$`: end of line

Command #2 breakdown:

- `grep`: Prints all the lines matching a regex in a file
- `'^sudo.+:\K.*$'`: makes `grep` match the regex between the quotes
- `cut`: Prints only a specified section of each line in a file
- `-d:`: makes `cut` interpret `:` as a field delimiter
- `-f4`: makes `cut` print only the fourth field

Regex #2 breakdown:

- Any character or group of characters not listed matches the character or the group of characters itself
- `^`: start of line
- `.*`: zero or more characters
- `$`: end of line

Comment: -1: this won't catch other users or groups who may have been added to sudoers, or external sources like LDAP, and boy is it an ugly way to do this. `getent group sudo | cut -d: -f4`, or use awk, but either way remember that group and passwd have fixed formats, with delimiters.

Comment: @muru You're right, I updated my answer

Comment: @kos Also note the you really should use `getent group` - you don't need the grep at all. `getent group foo` is like `grep foo /etc/group`, but more capable.

Comment: @muru I didn't know `getent` at all, any tought on how `grep` and `getent` compare computationally? Would it be lighter to run `getent`?

Comment: @kos I hope not. `getent` has access to more databases than `/etc/passwd`, it should certainly be doing more work. On the other hand, it is a dedicated tool.

Comment: You may use awk, `awk -F: '/^sudo/{print $NF}' /etc/group`

Comment: @muru Ok, I added the `getent` option as a third "possibly heavier" option

Comment: @AvinashRaj I *think* that the difference here should be really minor (if there's a difference at all), but any tought on how `grep` and `awk` compare performance-wise?

Comment: This answer assumes that all sudoers are members of the `sudo` group. Some unixes have other groups such as `wheel`. The answer by @muru will include all sudoers no matter what groups they are in.

Comment: this popular answer is a vivid example of how unusable everything "linux" is ...

Answer (score 40):

As it stated [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50785/how-do-i-find-out-if-i-am-sudoer) I consider the simpliest way to discover with `-l` & `-U` options together, just type `users` it will list e.g.: `John` then:

If the user has `sudo` access, it will print the level of `sudo` access for that particular user:

```
  sudo -l -U John
  User John may run the following commands on this host:
     (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

If the user don't have sudo access, it will print that a user is **not allowed** to run `sudo` on localhost:

```
   sudo -l -U John
   User John is not allowed to run sudo on localhost.
```

Comment: You could loop through all the normal users and return the details on them using [something like](http://askubuntu.com/a/633911/178596): `for u in $(awk -F'[/:]' '{if($3>=1000&&$3!=65534) print $1}' /etc/passwd); do sudo -lU "$u" ; done`. quick hack nothing guaranteed :)

Comment: This also works in a active directory setup. For instance you can pick a user from some special group and check on the user. If you added the AD group correctly something like `"%domain admins@mycompany.intra" ALL=(ALL) ALL` then it works. You saved me a lot of time, because I was unaware this works for non-local users as well.

Answer (score 19):

Expanding on the `sudo -l -U` test, one can use `getent passwd` to determine the users who can use `sudo`. Using [`getent`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/getent.1) allows us to access users who may not be present in the `passwd` file, such as LDAP users:

```
getent passwd | cut -f1 -d: | sudo xargs -L1 sudo -l -U | grep -v 'not allowed'
```

`sudo -U` does not return a non-zero exit value that we could take advantage of, so we are reduced to grepping the output.

Comment: This is the best answer because it doesn't assume that there is a group called `sudo`.

Answer (score 17):

As it has already been stated, the answer can be found on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140968/view-list-of-sudoers-with-no-sudo-priviledges/140974):

> This shows that user "saml" is a member of the wheel group.
>
> ```
> $ getent group wheel
> wheel:x:10:saml
> ```

The only difference is that the group in Ubuntu is not `wheel`, but `sudo` (or `admin` in older versions of Ubuntu). So the command becomes:

```
getent group sudo
```

Comment: What do these numbers mean? I did `geten group` and I see a lot of different numbers. My original question is, how to find out if a user is a system user (created with `useradd -r`)

Answer (score 9):

Command:

```
cat /etc/group | grep sudo
```

Output:

```
sudo:x:27:Tom,Stacy
```

Tom, Stacy are the users with sudo privileges.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Just to let you know, this is a [useless use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat).

Answer (score 3):

On most Unix-like systems, that have the sudo command, and have a sudo configuration file; running visudo as root:

```
:~$ sudo bash
```

or

```
:~$ su

:~# visudo
```

will allow an administrator to inspect and amend the privileges of groups that can use the sudo command.

On Debian based Unix-like systems, like Ubuntu, the groups 4 and 27 generally have access rights to the sudo privileges.

Group 4 is the administrator group (adm) and group 27 is the sudo gid.

To see what users are currently assigned to these groups cat the /etc/group file as shown below:

```
:~$ cat /etc/group
```

A sample output, on Ubuntu (but not Redhat based, Oracle Solaris/Solaris based, or BSD based systems) would yield this:

```
adm:x:4:youruser
tty:x:5:
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:
mail:x:8:
news:x:9: 
uucp:x:10:
man:x:12:
proxy:x:13:
kmem:x:15:
dialout:x:20:
fax:x:21:
voice:x:22:
cdrom:x:24:youruser,mybrother
floppy:x:25:
tape:x:26:
sudo:x:27:youruser,mybrother
```

As we can tell, youruser is the administrator of the system, and member of 
group 4 (adm). But youruser and mybrother are both members of group 27, which is the gid (group identification) number of group sudo. So mybrother can also attain root privileges (super user).

Many linux systems like Fedora and Slackware, incorporate the wheel group gid=10. Which allows administrator privileges when the sudo command is applied. On BSD based systems (e.g. FreeBSD), the root user is a member of the wheel group which is gid 0.

Also by using the id command any user can find the group information of another known user to the system.

For Example:

```
:~$ id mybrother
```

Sample output

```
uid=1001(mybrother) gid=1001(mybrother) groups=1001(mybrother),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare)
```

Comment: I specially logged in to upvote you. Perfect explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

This command returns a list of users with sudo rights:

```
awk -F ":" '{ system("groups " $1 " | grep -P \"[[:space:]]sudo([[:space:]]|$)\"") }' /etc/passwd
```

Output is (e.g.):

```
<username> : <username> adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker
```

If only the user name to be displayed, then this command:

```
awk -F ":" '{ system("groups " $1 " | grep -P \"[[:space:]]sudo([[:space:]]|$)\"") }' | awk -F ":" '{ print $1 }' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: it shows more users than the sudoers. It needs some modifications

Comment: @NewUSer Is that better?

Comment: Much better. Gd work

Answer (score 1):

I was stumped about how the `vagrant` user can use `sudo` even without being mentioned in `/etc/sudoers` nor in `/etc/group` nor found with `getent`.

Turns out **`sudo` also reads entries from all files under `/etc/sudoers.d/`**. So if you haven't looked through that directory, you may not realize how many users actually have `sudo` access.

This kind of `sudo` access can be detected by JoKeR's answer using `sudo -l -U vagrant` but is not detected by any of the other answers here which all rely on either `getent` or `/etc/group`.

Comment: It is worth noting that the reason for this is these lines in the config file (/etc/sudoers):  

  
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

Answer (score 0):

Based on answers from @muru and @kos, but with some optimizations.

The `getent group sudo` command lists only users who have the sudo group. The rest of the commands test whether the user is actually capable of running as root. There are also other additions to improve the formatting of the output.

**COMMAND**

```
if [ -z $(getent group sudo) ]; then printf "\n >>>>>>>>>>> NO ENTRIES <<<<<<<<<<<\n\n"; 
else getent group sudo | 
sed 's/.*://' | 
sed 's/,/\n/g' | 
xargs -L1 sudo -l -U | 
grep -v 'not allowed' | 
sed 's/Matching Defaults entries/\n >>>>>>>>>>> CAN RUN COMMANDS AS ROOT >>>>>>>>>>>\n\nMatching Defaults entries/g' | 
sed '$a\\'; fi
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 >>>>>>>>>>> CAN RUN COMMANDS AS ROOT >>>>>>>>>>>

Matching Defaults entries for may_user_i on localhost:
    !visiblepw, always_set_home, match_group_by_gid, always_query_group_plugin, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY", secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin

User may_user_i may run the following commands on localhost:
    (ALL) ALL
    (ALL) ALL

 >>>>>>>>>>> CAN RUN COMMANDS AS ROOT >>>>>>>>>>>

Matching Defaults entries for may_user_ii on localhost:
    !visiblepw, always_set_home, match_group_by_gid, always_query_group_plugin, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY", secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin

User may_user_ii may run the following commands on localhost:
    (ALL) ALL
```

**Thanks! =D**

**[Refs.:** https://askubuntu.com/a/611607/134723 , 
https://askubuntu.com/a/611646/134723 , 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136798/61742 , 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26639/61742 **]**