# parsing `/etc/passwd` to find root user, and whether user can run interactive shell

Tags: password, users, passwd

I want to parse `/etc/passwd` file to find out if the user has root privilege and can run interactive shell.

according to

> UID 100-999 are reserved by system for administrative and system accounts/groups

what I understood is if the UID is between 100 and 999,the user has root privilege. Am I right?

next is 
How do you say user can run interactive shell by reading `/etc/passwd`?

**PS. I am parsing this files in python, I can implement the logic, I just don't know the how to find out root user and what is Interactive shell and how to find one.**

Comment: One question per post please

Comment: @Serg, next time sure. But I thought they are related, so asked in same post.

Comment: Also it's not enough to find all system accounts. Regular users with id 1000 and higher can run admin tasks with sudo, so technically they have root privileges

Comment: What's the main premise of the question?  Also split out your questions - one question per posted quesiton

Comment: @Serg I am new to Linux environment, so please bear with me.

Comment: @Serg okay. will you please write a answer and explain me the file.

Comment: OK, will do in a minute

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/611584/how-could-i-list-all-super-users

Comment: In any case as it has been said already really you should split the second question into a new in question, please do that.

Comment: @kos, let me do that

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/728171/parsing-etc-passwd-file-to-find-users-with-interactive-shells here I have added my second question. Please so answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two types of accounts, system and regular user. System accounts belong to services and daemons, such as `lightdm`, `dnsmasq`, etc.Typically you cannot login into those accounts (although there are ways).

Regular users, such as your account or other people  accounts, can login and interact with the OS through shell (could be `bash`, `ksh`, `mksh`, `csh`, or graphical shell such as `Gnome` or `Unity`).

System accounts range from 100 to 999 by default. There exists one special case, `nobody` , who has ID of 65534 (That's the max UID number ). On my system for instance `dnsmasq` it runs `dnsmasq` service.

Regular user accounts have UID range from 1000 to 65533. Those users can login, unless their password is disabled or their entry in `/etc/passwd` has shell set to `/usr/sbin/nologin`, or prevented in some other way. These users can have root privilege if they belong to `sudo` group.

So if you want to find users who have `sudo` privilege you need to parse `/etc/group` file. Here's mine:

```
$ awk '/sudo/' /etc/group                                      
sudo:x:27:xieerqi,testuser
```

To get just the users, use `:` as separator and print 4th field.

```
$ awk -F':' '/sudo/{print $4}' /etc/group                      
xieerqi,testuser
```

In python this is done as so:

```
>>> with open("/etc/group") as file:
...    for lines in file:
...       if lines.__contains__("sudo"):
...          print lines.split(":")[3]
```

Here's even more interesting approach. How about if we want to take all the `sudo` users and see if they have a shell set up in `/etc/passwd` ?

```
$ awk -F':' '/sudo/{gsub(/\,/,"\n");print $4 }' /etc/group | xargs -I {} grep '^{}\:.*' /etc/passwd               
xieerqi:x:1000:1000:xieerqi,,,:/home/xieerqi:/bin/mksh
testuser:x:1001:1001:,,,:/home/testuser:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Always welcome ! Welcome to the site, and feel free to ask more questions

Comment: I am splitting question, in separate question. Please do answer that too.

Comment: I am parsing this files in python, I can implement the logic, I just don't know the how to find out root user and what is Interactive shell and how to find one.

Comment: So . . .python, huh ?  Let me think how that can be done . . .

Comment: `import grp; grp.getgrnam('sudo').gr_mem`

Answer (score 0):

In python this would be done like

```py
import grp
import pwd
print([x for x in grp.getgrnam('sudo').gr_mem if pwd.getpwnam(x).pw_shell not in ('/bin/false', '/bin/nologin')])
```

Where `grp.getgrnam('sudo').gr_mem` would return all group members of group `sudo` and `pwd.getpwnam(USER).pw_shell` returns the users shell from `/etc/passwd`.

---

But only group membership in `sudo` is not the only way to become root. Your users could also have individual entries in `/etc/sudoers` which would give them root permissions. So you'd need to parse `/etc/sudoers` as well.