# parsing `/etc/passwd` file to find users with Interactive shells

Tags: command-line, python

I want to parse `/etc/passwd` file to find out if the user can run interactive shell.

I know the 7th field in each line of `/etc/passwd` file tells the path of shell. But How do you say that, defined shell is interactive?

I am parsing this files in python, I can implement the logic, I just don't know the how to find out how to identify Interactive shell.

**PS. I want to find it out using python.**

Comment: Do you want to check if the shell can run interactively? otherwise the question is implementation dependent and ambiguous..

Comment: I didn't read the question like that before... If they can run a shell they can run it interactively. How do you run a shell "non-interactively" (script) without running it from an interactive shell? Unless you mean running a script from a desktop environment.

Comment: @heemayl actually I am new to linux, I will appreciate if you explain what is Interactive shell and how do you identify one.

Comment: Check [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46856/68757) ..as you don't understand the difference it is probably wiser to either remove or rephrase the question..

Comment: Parse [`/etc/shells`](http://askubuntu.com/a/616684/158442).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a basic misconception: talking of a shell that you cannot run interactively but that you can run non-interactively is much like talking of a car that you can't drive but that you can use to listen to the radio.

The main purpose of a shell is running interactively, the fact that it can run non-interactively is the optional, not the other way around.

Closer to the concept of a shell that you cannot run interactively but that you can run non-interactively is an interpreted language which can't be interpreted interactively (though one real example is not occuring to me right now: the most common interpreted languages all can run interactive sessions: Perl, Python, PHP, ...)

That been said if you want to find out whether a user *is allowed to login through a shell*, you can use this command:

```bsh
shell=$(getent passwd user | cut -d ':' -f 7); [ "$shell" = "/usr/sbin/nologin" -o "$shell" = "/bin/false" ] && printf 'User is not allowed to login\n' || printf '%s\n' "$shell"
```

(replace `user` in the `getent passwd user` command with the user's username)

In Python you could do:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
user = "user"
with open("/etc/passwd") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.split(":")[0] == user:
            if line.rstrip("\n").split(":")[6] in ["/usr/sbin/nologin", "/bin/false"]:
                print("User is not allowed to login")
            else:
                print(line.rstrip("\n").split(":")[6])
```

(replace `user` in the `user = "user"` statement with the user's username)

Or, as suggested by muru, better using the `pwd` module:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
from pwd import getpwnam

user = "user"
shell = getpwnam(user)[6]
if shell in ["/usr/sbin/nologin", "/bin/false"]:
    print("User is not allowed to login")
else:
    print(shell)
```

(replace `user` in the `user = "user"` statement with the user's username)

In all of the examples above if the seventh field of the user's `/etc/passwd` entry is either `/usr/sbin/nologin` or `/usr/bin/false` a message saying that the user is not allowed to login is printed; otherwise the user's login shell is printed.

But keep in mind that **not being able to login through a shell doesn't mean the user is not allowed to login at all, and that there might be bogus shells other than `/usr/sbin/nologin` or `/bin/false` used to forbid the user's login**. You should watch out for those too.

Comment: Also, there's the `pwd` library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pwd.html

Comment: @muru Huh right, I forgot I was pasting from the terminal. And yeah looks better using `in`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through file splitting each line into fields and check if 6th field doesn't contain "no-login" for all the lines where UID is greater than 1000

```
>>> with open("/etc/passwd") as file:
...     for line in file:
...        if  int(line.split(":")[2])  > 1000  and not str(line.split(":")[6]).__contains__("nologin"):
...            print line
... 
testuser:x:1001:1001:,,,:/home/testuser:/bin/bash

tester:x:1002:1002:TESTER,,,:/home/tester:/bin/bash

newUser:x:1003:1003::/home/newUser:

testUser:x:1004:1004::/home/testUser:

testuser2:x:1005:1005:asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf:/home/testuser2:/bin/bash
```

Usernames who have shell set can login with that shell, for instance `xieerqi` has `/bin/mksh`, while `testUser` has `/bin/bash`. Other users don't have shell set, which will default to `/bin/bash`

Comment: you mean all shells are Interactive except with the `no-login`?

Comment: Serg, i am afraid the question is pretty ambiguous and your answer is not properly directed too..its not your fault actually as the OP is not clear about differences among shell sessions..

Comment: heemayl exactly I am not clear about the shell concept.

Comment: @KishorPawar  All the common shells, such as `bash`, `ksh`, `csh` , `dash` - all those are interactive if you can type something with keyboard. If you are using them for running a script, that's non-interactive.  That's different question though. If a user has a shell set in `/etc/passwd` that means they can login interactively and control system using keyboard. So every user who has some form of shell set up (or like some of my users - blank ) those will be able to login and work interactively

Comment: You can also use `/bin/false` to disable the shell for a user