# I'm new to Linux, Ubuntu, how do add family members to login?

Tags: login

I'm new to linux/ubuntu with limited knowledge of computers, my windows system was infected, unable to use had Ubuntu installed.

How do I set up alternate user names for family members?

How do i download picture/videos from  my phone?

How do I create folders?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A command to list all users? And how to add, delete, modify users?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/410244/a-command-to-list-all-users-and-how-to-add-delete-modify-users)

Answer (score 8):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Typically, we ask that you refrain from asking multiple questions within one. I would suggest that in the future you keep your questions to a single question per post. Thanks!

As for adding other user accounts, it's fairly simple. Go up to the Unity Dash and search for `User Accounts`:

[image]

then click the <kbd>Unlock</kbd> button (with the little padlock in the upper-right-hand-corner) and then the <kbd>+</kbd> button:

[image]

and fill in the details:

[image]

You've just created a new user! You can repeat this as many times as you want, just so long as the usernames are different.

As for creating the folder, you can do this two ways.

**First Method - GUI Method**:

1. Open up Nautilus (the file manager, first icon underneath the main Unity button)
2. Navigate to the folder you want, then right click and select the first option `New Folder`:

[image]

**Second Method: Terminal**:

1. Open a Terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Navigate to the directory (folder) where you want to create the new directory. You can do this `cd`.
3. Type in `mkdir NEWFOLDERNAMEHERE`, obviously switching out the `NEWFOLDERNAMEHERE` with the folder name you want.

Answer (score 2):

## New user account

To create a new user account under Ubuntu use the command called `adduser`. gaining root privileges via the command `sudo`.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo adduser {username}
```

## New directory

To create a directory under Ubuntu use the command called `mkdir`.

For example, below we are creating a new directory called Books in the  /home/{user}/directory.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
mkdir /home/user/Books
```

## Manpages

[Manpage sudo](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man8/sudo.8.html)

[Manpage adduser](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man8/adduser.8.html)

[Manpage mkdir](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/mkdir.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that when I connect my phone to my laptop via the data cable it connects automatically. It comes up with a dialog box asking what action I wish to take. Sometimes when the phone is connected I have to change the source over to mass storage, but that is it.