# Only Guest User login is Available in my new Dell Vostro Laptop

Tags: login, dell

I bought a New Dell Vostro 3558 Laptop today. Ubuntu was pre-installed in that. However, i am facing the below 2 issues in it.

- Only Guest user login is available.
- Linux Terminal is not working in Guest user login

Could someone please advise what i should do now.

Comment: I would install a fresh copy of ubuntu 14lts. You coudld aslo look up the root user name then change the root password and add user but this task is daunting.

Comment: Sure please up vote my comment; )

Comment: You people seriously downvote a newcomer to the fun land of Ubuntu, unable to login? :)

Shame!

Comment: I don't understand why Dell pre-installs a guest-only Ubuntu in their notebooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user recovery password procedure to gain admin 
1. Use this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) to gain access to shell
2. Get list of existing users and find the admin username (and change his password using the above) or add new admin user. You can find details in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410244/a-command-to-list-all-users-and-how-to-add-delete-modify-users) on how to get list of users and adding  a new username.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do is add username in /etc/sudoers   file with full permissions and then use "sudo passwd root" to set new password

Comment: `/etc/sudoers` is owned by root, how will he edit it with his guest account? Please describe how to achieve this or link to another answer. If you intend to link to external sources, please copy the relevant parts here, to make sure the information is always available.