# How do you add user using the terminal?

Tags: users

How do you add a user in ubuntu using the terminal

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/410244/380067.

Answer (score 3):

**Here are the commands to add a new user with the username "newuser"**

*sudo adduser newuser*

*sudo passwd newuser*

Comment: Why did you answer yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the `useradd` command. Just issue:

`sudo useradd new-username`

Replacing `new-username` with the name you want.

Now let's set new-usernames's password:

`sudo passwd new-username`

You'll be prompted to type the new password twice. Nothing will be displayed on the screen while you do it.

If you want your user to be in groups such as sudo, volume, etc. you'll have to do it manually.