# Can't delete user account

Tags: command-line, users, user-management

In a terminal:

```
/home$ ls
abuabdullah  alzaabi  hussain  u942
```

Then I tried to delete account `u942` by using command line:

```
/home$ deluser u942
/usr/sbin/deluser: Only root may remove a user or group from the system.
```

Then I tried to use sudo

```
/home$ sudo deluser u942
/usr/sbin/deluser: The user `u942' does not exist.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did somebody just create a directory in `/home`? Is there a reason you think there's an account named `u942` in your system?

Comment: To verify that there is no such user: Whats the output of `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | grep u942`. (probably empty)

Comment: please add the output of `ls -lsd /home/u942` so we'll able to see the owner of this folder

Answer (score 8):

For root/sudo user it is possible to just create folders in `/home` that are not associated to any user account. That is why `ls /home` is not a good command to check for users.

To list all users that have their home folder below "/home", you can run:

```
getent passwd | grep "/home" | cut -d: -f1
```

[List all users](https://askubuntu.com/a/410274/631600): `getent passwd | cut -d: -f1`

Check if user u942 exists: `getent passwd | grep u942`. If you get no output, no such user exists.

If the output is empty, you can delete that folder (you might need sudo) `rm -Rf /home/u942`. But double check the contents of the folder before you delete it.

Comment: rm command won't work, to delete folder with content use `rm -rf /home/u942` instead. Note: Be careful, as with -rf flag you can easily delete anything.

Comment: You should actually use `getent passwd` instead of reading `/etc/passwd` manualy. In particular, to see if a `u942` is a user in the system: `getent passwd u942`.

Comment: Why "should" I. There is no problem with /etc/passwd. `getent passwd` gives me also non-local users, which I may or may not want.

Comment: You gave the reason: "non-local users". There's no guarantee that non-local users also have non-local home directories. "If you get no output, no such user exists" is not necessarily true if you only read `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: That is true. I edited the answer ...

Answer (score 3):

As you might know, it's possible to create a home directory differ from "username". For example I can have a user named "john" which its home directory is: `/home/jack`.

If you already know the user name, you could run:

```
echo ~username
```

It would print that specific user home directory. You can also run:

```
ls -ld /home/u942
```

or

```
stat -c %U /home/u942
```

to see which user owns this home directory then delete that user.

Also there is a chance that user is already deleted but its home directory not.

To find it out you can do something like:

```
id -un `stat -c %U /home/u942`
```

If it returned nothing it means the owner does not exist on your system. simply remove that directory *If only you believe there is no important file there*.