# There is a "Ubuntu" user account in my /home folder. I don't know where that came from

Tags: login, users

I'm using ubuntu MATE 16.04.

I'm the only one that uses this computer, as far as i know :/

I was checking on an old account that I had created a long time ago and noticed that it did not show up in the gui user manager. I don't remember removing it.

I went to my /home folder, at the command line, to see if the account folder was still there. It was gone, but there was a user folder "ubuntu" in home. "/home/ubuntu"

I didn't create that user-account/folder. It doesn't show up in the gui user manager either.

The permissions for the folder are:

```
drwx------  3 root    root    4096 Nov  1  2016 ubuntu
```

when I run Thunar using sudo I can access the folder but there's nothing in there that I can see.

I want to remove it. But, since I'm not a linux guru, I don't want to create any negative side effects by removing something that needs to be there.

Does anyone have an idea where this folder/account might have come from, and if it is needed or can be deleted?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: View this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/410244/119531) to check if there are any users that you don't recognize. Then follow the same answer to remove any unwanted user and directories related to it.

Comment: Thank you Raphael. I did just what you suggested and have gotten rid what I didn't recognize.