# Problem with tty terminal login

Tags: login, tty

I stuck at boot up sequence access so I open tty terminal by pressing ctrl + alt + F2. I have to login, but I forgot my login, I know only my password.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1. [boot into a root shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)
2. [print the list of users on your system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410244/a-command-to-list-all-users-and-how-to-add-delete-modify-users)

   ```
   cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
   ```

This should help you figuring out your username.