# Reset the password in Ubuntu / Linux Bash in Windows

Tags: password-recovery, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Linux Bash on Windows 10 (available from Microsoft), but I've forgotten my password.

I've searched for a solution but I only find suggestions that involve doing something before the system boots, like accessing recovery mode, but that will not work in this case as this Ubuntu is just an application within a Windows system and doesn't have its own boot process.

How can I reset my password?

Comment: Which password did you lose exactly? Your Windows account password?

Comment: an example "booting option" would be to boot to single user mode by setting kernel cmdline to "single" via grub. For those curious.

Answer (score 508):

- Run `bash` and make a note of your Linux username (this need not match your Windows username), see [How can I find out my user name?](https://askubuntu.com/q/333718/283843)
- Close Bash on Ubuntu if it is running (or the next command will fail).
- In Windows admin command prompt (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>) change the default user to root:

  ```
  ubuntu config --default-user root
  ```

If you are using Ubuntu 18.04 in WSL, the command has changed to `ubuntu1804` , so

```
ubuntu1804 config --default-user root
```

- Now Bash on Ubuntu on Windows logs you in as root without asking password
- Use `passwd` command in Bash to change the user password (the user whose password you want to reset):

  ```
  passwd your_username
  ```
- Change the default user back to your normal user in Windows command prompt

  ```
  ubuntu config --default-user  your_username
  ```

If you are using Ubuntu 18.04 in WSL, the command has changed to `ubuntu1804` , so

```
ubuntu1804 config --default-user your_username
```

Watch Full Video to Recover your password Windows Subsystem Linux
https://youtu.be/dTR232yvDCE

Note 1: The subsystem used in the video is not Ubuntu, but Kali    Linux. Hence the difference in the command.

Note 2: If you are still    using the original Ubuntu subsystem that came with the Anniversary Update, use the command *lxrun*. Upgrade to the subsystem version distributed via Microsoft Store is recommended.)

Comment: `lxrun` is for beta version of WSL. If you install ubuntu from the app store, the command is `ubuntu config --default-user root`.

Comment: Yeah, this is an alternative way but I got the error: `Failed to set default user to: root`.

Comment: @Kirby: you must log out from the WSL shell before running the command in the Windows command prompt.

Comment: I tried "ubuntu config --default-user root", and got an error says "ubuntu is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: I kept getting `Error: 0x80070057 The parameter is incorrect`, so I ended up following @dr01 's cue and ran `ubuntu` in PowerShell, then `logout`, then configured the default user again. Success 

Comment: If you installed ubuntu 18.04 on WSL, the command is `ubuntu1804` instead of `ubuntu`. Hope this saves some head-scratching.

Comment: @Indominus - I updated the answer with this information

Comment: I tried the guide, but it doesn't working at all, could you help me to have a look on it: 
[Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/MmuuD2d.png)

Comment: For me I used `lxrun /setdefaultuser root` to set the default user

Comment: Be aware that "Ubuntu" in this answer refers to the distribution you want to configure. This can also be "Suse" or "Debian", for example.

Comment: Also be aware that you will need to close all open WSL shells before the configuration goes into effect.

Comment: It is not necessary to run the Windows command prompt as admin. A normal user-privileged one works fine (because each WSL instance is user-local, not system-wide).

Comment: @Bob that was my experience as well, can just run regular command prompt and works fine.

Comment: If you have Ubuntu 20.04, use ```ubuntu2004```.

Comment: Keep getting `Error: 0x80070057 The parameter is incorrect`, this solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 147):

Microsoft has a good help page on this: [WSL User documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/user-support#forgot-your-password).

In Windows PowerShell (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd>) you can log in to the Ubuntu root account with

```
wsl --user root
```

Then change the password as you usually would, i.e. for the current user (which is root) with

```
passwd
```

or for another user with

```
passwd username
```

which interactively asks you for a new password (twice). Windows admin privileges are not required.

If you have more than one distribution installed in WSL, then you can list the names of the installed distributions with

```
wsl -l
```

and then use the name of the distribution to specify into which distribution you want to log in to, for example to log into Ubuntu 20.04:

```
wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04 --user root
```

Comment: Awesome! This works as of 10/2019. And, very important, this prompt command works even without administrator privileges on the Windows machine (that's a time- and money-saver if you're on a company PC).

Comment: That change root password - yes, after it just launch Ubuntu under Windows and under console type: 
$ su root
# passwd YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME

Comment: Didn't work on the VM because I don't know the old password.

Comment: @GringoSuave When you are root it doesn't ask for a password. Did you skip the first step or add additional ones in between?

Comment: Yes, figured it out.  Had to use `passwd user`.  Thanks.

Comment: it works.  thanks

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you for this awesome answer.

Comment: This seems to also be the way the [Microsoft recommends](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/user-support#forgot-your-password), FYI

Comment: @a11 Thanks for the hint.

Comment: This solved EG's laptop. Thanks.

Answer (score 74):

**Important**  *This answer is (a) for the older WSL1 only, (b) is outdated as it references paths that are no longer used by WSL1, even, and (c) most importantly, can cause filesystem corruption, [per Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/).  Please refer to other answers here for proper methods of changing the password.*

The above did not work. Even after changing default user, Bash always opened with my user.

So instead I did this, which worked:

1. Edit this file (in notepad or notepad++):

   ```
    %localappdata%\lxss\rootfs\etc\shadow
   ```
2. Find your normal user, for example:

   ```
    user1:$jsdjksadgfhsdf.saflsdf.sadf.safd:17299:0:99999:7:::
   ```

and simply remove the hash part (below part)

```
    $jsdjksadgfhsdf.saflsdf.sadf.safd
```

you will see a different hash - I hope :) so it should look like:

```
    user1::17299:0:99999:7:::
```

3. Save the file
4. Start Bash again with root privileges and set your password

   ```
     sudo bash
     passwd <your-user-name>
   ```

You can now set a new password without having to enter the previous one.

Comment: this works but the official directory is now similar to

%localappdata%\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\etc\shadow

Comment: This is the best answer _by far_.  To find the path to your `shadow` file you can use this PowerShell abomination: `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Filter shadow -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force` which is an insanely verbose version of `find /mnt/c/ -name shadow` in both execution and results. No need for elevated privileges to edit the file, but make sure your bash window is closed before you do it.

Comment: This is the winner! Worked great when the first answer did not.

Comment: The accepted answer got me 'Error: 0x80070057 The parameter is incorrect.'. (and no, the console was not in legacy mode). This worked seamlessly;

Comment: try to find the lxss, but it says `Windows can't find 'C:\Users\longnx\AppData\Local\lxss'. Check the spelling and try again.`

Comment: @Russ, why bash PS's verbosity (pun intended)? ;-) I'll add for the newbies that you should have included `2>/dev/null` in your `find` command since you ignored errors in your PS command. A more fair comparison might be: to be less verbose, ignore errors and (bonus!) change PS's output to be similar to that of `find` (without breaking out `awk`!), I'd offer 'find /mnt/c/ -name shadow 2>/dev/null` vs `dir c:\shadow -rec -ea si | select FullName`. Having said that, I usually use the long parameter forms in each shell since tab completion does the hard part anyway. Great comment, though.

Comment: This answer worked exactly as outlined above. The first answer did not work for me.

Comment: Your solution worked for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: NOTE : here rootfs folder refers to installation directory or WSL

Comment: This won't work with WSL2 as the LInux filesystem is now a VHDX image.

Answer (score 28):

**Edit** This no longer works if you have a store-installed distribution of WSL.

To add to Tmu's answer, here's a Powershell script ([gist](https://gist.github.com/richardszalay/8e2b9cae0dfe654ed0b8bfcaab361966)) that automates the process (including automatically detecting the current default username)

```powershell
# Resets the password for the default LXSS / WSL bash user
$lxssUsername = (Get-ItemProperty HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss).DefaultUsername
lxrun /setdefaultuser root
bash -c "passwd $lxssUsername"
lxrun /setdefaultuser $lxssUsername
```

Comment: getting E r r o r :   0 x 8 0 0 7 0 0 0 2 in powershell

Answer (score 6):

I needed to reset my password also in my Windows 10, I has WLS 1

1- Check your linux/ubuntu name, listing the folder:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
```

In my case **I found Ubuntu1604.exe**, so I will use **ubuntu1604** like name for the next step.
[image: list files in: %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps]

2- Open CMD with administrator privilegies and run (you will get nothing in return):

```
ubuntu1604 config --default-user root
```

3- Start your WSL, check that you get root privilegues or run whoami (you need to be root) and change your password with:

```
passwd [your-linux-username]
```

4- Close your WSL and get back to the CMD Window and set back your default linux username:

```
ubuntu1604 config --default-user [your-linux-username]
```

5- Start your WSL/Ubuntu/AnotherLinux again, check and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here, while mostly valid, are vastly overcomplicated.  To change your user password in *any* WSL distribution, simply:

From inside Ubuntu (or another distribution):

```
wsl.exe \~ -u root -d $WSL_DISTRO_NAME -e passwd $USER
```

<sup>*<sub>Requires WSL Interop to be enabled.</sub></sup>

Or from PowerShell or CMD (as a *regular*, non-admin user):

```
wsl ~ -u root -e passwd <username>
# Add the -d <distro_name> if not using the default distro
```

<sup>*<sub>Does not require WSL Interop.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who lost the root password, what worked for me, was updating to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS via the Windows Store. Note, the windows store has two distinct options:

1. Ubuntu
2. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (**Pick this one**)

To check your current version, run the following as any user:

At command prompt, enter:

```
cat /etc/*release
```

You should see a line in the output that says:

```
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.01
```

If you see that, then definitely [update to 18.04](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/update-ubuntu-18-04-on-windows-10/), and it will prompt you to create new UNIX credentials.