# Password change doesn't persist after restart

Tags: xubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently set up WSL on my computer, I used the same password I use for windows to sudo in the Ubuntu terminal.  I was able to sudo after it was first installed, but when I turned my system back on the next day, it is telling me my password is incorrect. I was able to successfully change the password with the solution to the question asked below.  But whenever the computer is restarted, it tells me that the password doesn't work.  How do I make the setting change persist after the computer is shut down?  Thank you for your time.

[Reset the Password in Linux Bash in Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772050/reset-the-password-in-linux-bash-in-windows/808425#808425?newreg=faf4415d17f844f9b973c9bea5ef7f1f)