# How to reset password of Ubuntu app 16.04 on Windows 10

Tags: password, password-recovery, reset

I have installed Ubuntu app 16.04 from the Microsoft store. Now I have forgotten the password of the ubuntu user. How to reset it?

Thanks you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reset the password in Ubuntu / Linux Bash in Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772050/reset-the-password-in-ubuntu-linux-bash-in-windows)

Comment: I was tried "ubuntu config --default-user root" and "lxrun /setdefaultuser root" but have error. ubuntu: "command not found" and "lxrun: command not found"

Comment: @ThienHoang Look further down through the answers.  There is one dated back in October 2019:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1171006/231142