# Ubuntu bash windows forgot password

Tags: password, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I forgot the password for the Ubuntu bash on windows. I tried to reset it by following the instructions https://www.top-password.com/blog/forgot-linux-bash-password-in-windows-10/ but the windows cmd threw the following:

> 'ubuntu' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I tried with both, ubuntu and ubuntu1806/04. I also tried `passwd root` but it says "you may not view or modify password".

I have tried `wsl -u root` but it says wsl is not installed. If I try to install it, I need to input the password.

I also tried to uninstall the ubuntu bash, when I click uninstall on the task bar, it redirects me to the control panel option for uninstalling programs, but it is not shown on the list to uninstall it. How can I reset the password?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reset the password in Ubuntu / Linux Bash in Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772050/reset-the-password-in-ubuntu-linux-bash-in-windows)

Comment: Since you're getting `ubuntu isn't a recognized command`, please verify the Ubuntu app you're using. If it's Ubuntu, command will be `ubuntu` but for 18.04, it'll be `ubuntu1804` and for 16.04, it'll be `ubuntu1604`. Moreover, control panel only shows program which were installed using executables instead of Windows Store, i.e. it shows programs with executables not [UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform)

Comment: yes, I tried with both, ubuntu and ubuntu1806/04.
I also tried 
passwd root
but it says "you may not view or modifz password"
I have tried wsl -u root but it says wsl it's not install. If I try to install it I need to input the password

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using? Do you receive insiders updates?

Comment: windows 10 home 64 bit. Normally it updates regularly

Comment: Open Powershell as admin and run `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux` and then reboot the system. Try `wsl -l -v`.

Answer (score 7):

if you forgot password for your own account then try to login with root user and reset it for your account (instruction mentioned below).

```
# passwd <your_user>
```

if you forgot password for the root account; try to open a root shell with `sudo -i` and type your own user's password and change the password for the root account.

```
# passwd root
```

---

Another options is [resetting from Windows Powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/user-support) for newer Windows10 version:

1. Open PowerShell and enter the root of your default WSL distribution using the command:

   ```
   wsl -u root
   ```
2. If you need to update the forgotten password on a distribution that is not your default, use the command: `wsl -d Debian -u root`, replacing `Debian` with the name of your targeted distribution.
3. Once your WSL distribution has been opened at the root level inside PowerShell, you can use this command to update your password: `passwd`
4. You will be prompted to enter a new UNIX password and then confirm that password. Once you're told that the password has updated successfully, close WSL inside of PowerShell using the command: `exit`

---

[this is for previous versions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/user-support-archived):

**For Creators Update version of Windows and earlier**

If you're running Windows 10 Creators update or earlier, you can change the default Bash user by running the following commands:

1. Change the default user to root:

   ```
   C:\> lxrun /setdefaultuser root
   ```
2. Run `bash.exe` to now login as `root`:

   ```
   C:\> bash.exe
   ```
3. Reset your password using the distribution's password command, and close the Linux Console:

   ```
   # passwd username
   # exit
   ```
4. From Windows CMD, reset your default user back to your normal Linux user account:

   ```
   C:\> lxrun.exe /setdefaultuser username
   ```

**For Fall Creators Update and later**

To see what commands are available for a particular distribution, run `[distro.exe] /?` (replace `distro` with the distribution name you have installed like `ubuntu.exe /?`).

Step by step instructions using Ubuntu:

1. Open CMD
2. Set the default Linux user to `root`:

   ```
   C:\> ubuntu config --default-user root
   ```
3. Launch your Linux distribution (`ubuntu`). You will automatically login as `root`.
4. Reset your password using the `passwd` command:

   ```
   # passwd username
   ```
5. From Windows CMD, reset your default user back to your normal Linux user account.

   ```
   C:\> ubuntu config --default-user username
   ```

**Note**: Replace `ubuntu` with `ubuntu1604` or `ubuntu1804` if you're using Ubuntu 16.04 or Ubuntu 18.04 app.

Answer (score -1):

To change Password of ubuntu bash user here is step

open windows power shell
type below command in shell

```
PS C:\Users\user.name> wsl -u root
```

here we access root user of wsl if you have any other use then write below command ( for example )

```
PS C:\Users\user.name> wsl -u [username]
```

it will show like this

```
username:/mnt/c/Users/user.name$
```

then write below command

```
passwd [username]
```

this will show like

```
New password:
```

now write new password and retype new password and hit Enter now **restart lxssManager service**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1288396)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  This appears to be the same as an option mentioned in [this existing answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1225867/1165986).  You are welcome to [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1225867/edit) that answer if you feel there's a need to make something more clear, but I don't believe it's necessary to add a new answer in this case.  Thanks!