# How to recover lost 20.04.1.0 administrative password on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Tags: password, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How do I either recover or reset my admin password in a situation where I installed Ubuntu using the Windows Subsystem for Linux?  I am running Ubuntu 20.04.1.0.

Comment: No, because that thread is for Ubuntu 18.04.  What's more, the suggestions posted there are inconsistent.

Comment: The answer has not changed since 18.04.  There are multiple answers.

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1171006/1165986) is really the only one that makes sense today.  The others are either wrong, out-dated, or even dangerous (as they recommend editing the filesystem in a way that Microsoft says can cause corruption).  I'd honestly rather provide a new, correct, up-to-date answer here on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there just *isn't* a root password in WSL, since (a) your normal user has `sudo` rights and (b) running `wsl -u root` gets you full root access without a password. There's really not much of a concept of "login", except for a few special situations like SSH.

Is there something you are doing that requires a root password?  You should be able to set it with `wsl -u root passwd` (from PowerShell or cmd), although I'm not at my PC to try it out at the moment.

If you need to reset the password of your primary user, perhaps for `sudo` access, then `wsl -u root passwd username`.