# how do I reset my password when I already make it a no password in Windows 10 system?

Tags: 20.04

I am Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)

And I forgot what I did but now I am able to get this $ sign in my prompt.

However, now I am trying to follow a tutorial where the steps include :

karen@DESKTOP-SB41UI7:~$    wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
[sudo] password for karen:

But, I remember I have set a no password required in my laptop...for Ubuntu access.
For this case, how do I go about reset the password or make it like no need password forever ?
Tks.

Comment: hi @vidarlo, but mine is with my name and not root@DESKTOP-SB41UI7 so does it mean that karen@@DESKTOP-SB41UI7 is referring to root? I have spent countless hours to make it $ and configured so much things that I forgot what I did before.  Kindly advise me. Tks.

Comment: See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1171006/653515) answer. Simply run `passwd karen` to change password for that user, after first running `wsl --user root`

Comment: @vidarlo, I hope this will not revert things to wsl status because I tried so hard to get wsl2 installed and I would hate to repeat the process again and I did not copy down all the steps how I did it.

Comment: @vidarlo, i did wls --user root in the windows command prompt but it gives me a name that is same as under C:\Users\PersonName but what I want is to change the karen's and not the PersonName...how do I go about making things happen correctly?

Comment: Read the linked answer. `passwd username` will change password for `username`.

Comment: @vidarlo I managed to switch it to root and there is no need to enter the password.  So, I managed to install jenkins and nginx on Ubuntu.  The issue now is how to change back to the $ and with my username?

Comment: Ask a new question about your issue. It's quite distinct from changing password.

Comment: ok. sure. tks :)